# Google Play Games y GoogleMobileAds no trabajan juntos en Unity 5

Tags: android, unity3d, admob

Saludos, estoy trabajando en un juego en **Unity3D** y tengo integrados los servicios de **google play games**, pero a la hora de importar el plugin de **GoogleMobileAds** me lanza errores que no sé cómo solucionar.

Utilizo:

- Unity 5.3.5f1 Personal,
- Google Play Games Plugin 0.9.34,
- Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.1.0.

Los dos plugins funcionan bien solos, el problema ocurre cuando importo ambos plugins, me lanza estos dos errores:

> Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs(146,56):
>   error CS0433: The imported type `Google.JarResolver.Dependency' is
>   defined multiple times

Y

> Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GPGSDependencies.cs(37,23): error
>   CS0433: The imported type `Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport' is
>   defined multiple times

Agradezco mucho su ayuda, ya que soy nuevo en esto y no só cómo resolver este problema.

Comment: Mirate unitiyAds que son expresamente para el framework de juegos , dejo el enlace https://unity3d.com/es/services/ads

Comment: Desconozco totalmente unity y ads, googleando he encontrado eso http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/979590/unity-5-error-the-imported-type-is-defined-multipl.html si lo solventas el problema, puedes agegar tu respuesta así otros usuarios podemos tener referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que ambos te están metiendo el playserviceresolver que sirve para que te agregen automaticamente las librerías necesarias en Android (como la de support-v4 o play-games-services-basement).

Mira a ver si tienes 2 carpetas llamadas PlayServicesResolver y borra una de ellas. Eso debería solucionar el problema.